# Most effective way to iterate over only the values from an Enum that begin with certain characters

Tags: java, string, enums

I have an Enum class with a huge amount of values (translation keys to use with the database),
but in my case I would only need to iterate over values of it which start for example with characters "c_foo_"

What would be the most cost efficient way to do this?

I'm using Java 14.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: You can use a `Trie` or a `PatriciaTrie` if you are only interested in values starting with a certain prefix. Java natively does not provide an implementation, however, Apache Commons does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `Stream`s from the enum's values to filter out those you're not interested in.

```
Arrays.stream(YourEnum.values())
    .filter(e -> e.name().startsWith("c_foo_"))
    .forEach(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way could be, presupposed your enum values have a defined order:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    BAR, BAZ, DOO, FOO, GEE, MOO
}
```

you could use `EnumSet.range` :

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> set = EnumSet.range(MyEnum.BAZ, MyEnum.GEE);
```

to get all the elements from BAZ to GEE following the order defined in the enum

```
[BAZ, DOO, FOO, GEE]
```

Notice that both first and last elements are inclusiv.

Comment: A valid solution, but general guidelines (for example Effective Java, Item 35: _Instance fields instead of ordinals_ [Bloch]) do not recommend to rely on the `ordinal()` method of an enum. Relying on alphanumeric ordering would imply the same.